# In dialogflow, how to upload file containing questions and answers programmatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Can we upload a training data (in .txt) using Python code in Dialogflow or Google cloud platform using Detect intent and Agent API ? If so, please share your insights.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at using a [PUT request](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents#put_intentsid_sample) to add additional training data to your intents. However, there is not a direct option to upload a text file. Generally Dialogflow does a really good job of interpreting the user's intent with just a handful of training samples, making it feasible to type each in manually or copy & paste. As it uses machine learning to match similar phrases, it shouldn't be necessary to upload a large text file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you for training phrases you can upload one .txt file(one line per phrase) or multiple .txt zipped archive files(there's a limit of 10).

There's more on this here in the [docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/training-analytics/training).